# How to retrieve Stripe customer having cancelled, unpaid or past_due subscription?

Tags: php, wordpress, stripe-payments

Currently I am able retrieve Stripe customer having active subscription but i also want to retrieve other subscription status like unpaid, past_due and cancelled.

```
$customer = \Stripe\Customer::retrieve( $customer_id );
$customer_subscriptions_list = $customer->subscriptions->all(array())['data'];
$customer_subscriptions = array ();

foreach ($customer_subscriptions_list  as  $customer_subscription) {
            $customer_subscriptions[] = $customer->subscriptions->retrieve( $customer_subscription['id'] );
      }

return $customer_subscriptions;
```

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: Maybe read the Stripe API docs?

Comment: And yet it took me about 20 seconds to find the answer to your question there...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answer is directly in the docs: https://stripe.com/docs/api#list_subscriptions

Comment: @koopajah I understand the question might be straight forward to you. I am trying to different API /stripe/customer instead of /stripe/subscription. Thanks

Comment: @AlexHowansky@koopajah Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($customer_subscriptions as $customer_subscription){
            if($customer_subscription->status == "past_due" || $customer_subscription->status == "unpaid"){
                existing code
            }
```

My fault i thought /stripe/customer only retrieve Active subscription. I have change subscription from "Active" to "un_paid" and then the code worked fine.